# How to version control a directory in a Mercurial repository using CVS?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, directory, cvs, symlink

I have a Mercurial repository `hg-repo` which has a directory `cvs-dir` that I want to simultaneously version control in CVS, and commit to a CVS repository:

```
$ ls hg-repo
cvs-dir other
```

The rest of the Mercurial repository such as `other` should not be bothered by CVS any how. How to set this up?

### Edit

If I simply create a symbolic link (`ln -s`) to `cvs-dir` in a different CVS working copy directory `cvs-repo`

```
$ pwd
 /home/foo
$ ls
hg-repo cvs-repo
$ ls -a cvs-repo
cvs-dir  -> /home/foo/hg-repo/cvs-dir
```

then

1. do any CVS work from within `/home/foo/cvs-repo` such as committing the working copy to CVS repository;
2. write `.cvsignore` to ignore Mercurial meta data, and vice versa,

will this method have some potential problems?

Answer (score 0):

This can help and is how I do this

First: Get the CVS repository locally.

Second: Create a mercurial repositories locally over this CVS repository. This will be used as your remote mercurial server.

Third: Clone this mercurial repository and do you work here.

Mercurial provides better merge support than cvs and will make your work easier. Commit back to CVS needs an extra step. Here is how this works, step-by-step. The workflow looks complicated, but is actually easy. Keep the flow-charts close.

[Detailed step-by-step explanaition with flowchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879829/how-to-use-mercurial-locally-with-a-central-cvs-repository)